# Flagged question not removed

Tags: discussion, flags

Trying to make SO a better place and contributing as much as possible I try to flag and edit when the opportunity arises.

When I flag questions and later look back at my helpful flags I notice that either 2 things have happened:

1. User deleted the question
2. SO community/moderators deleted the question

now I recently flagged this question : [Could I....](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36766414/could-i-have-ask-the-visitors-like-my-post-on-facebook-for-readmore)

8 days later the flag was helpful, but the post is still there. To get a better understanding of how SO handles flagging my question is:

Is there a reason to keep some kind of helpful flagged questions? Or does it have to do with the kind of flag?

Comment: Your flag was marked helpful 1 minute after you flagged it when a user with 3k cast a similar close vote - the question just didn't gather enough close votes to be closed (although I'm sure it will now...)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Whenever you flag a question (as off-topic, or as a duplicate of another question), it ends up in the [Close Vote review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review). At the moment, there are over 9000 questions waiting for review; with such a large backlog, it is not illogical that only one user got it as a review (this can be seen from the [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/36766414/timeline)). The reviewer agreed with your flag, so it was marked as helpful. But, because it takes five close votes to close a question, it wasn't closed - until you brought the [meta effect](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235225/what-is-the-meta-effect) upon it.

Comment: This gives me a basic overview of how the proces goes. Thank you and Jon Clements for the explaining.